# Internal Page Links vs Different Page via HTML

Tags: html, linux, hyperlink, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google ignores whatever is after the hash fragment (#) while crawling our website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001433/does-google-ignores-whatever-is-after-the-hash-fragment-while-crawling-our-w)

I have a question regarding links to a different section of the same page vs linking to a new page. For example:

```
domain.com/about.php
domain.com/history.php
domain.com/team.php
```

vs.

```
domain.com/about.php
domain.com/about.php#history
domain.com/about.php#team
```

I am wondering if Google recognizes the 2nd set of links and indexes those pages separately? Or if just the about.php page is indexed? Ideally I will remove the .php extension in nginx config.

thanks.

Comment: For a search engine the '.php' extension is not relevant. Removing that only makes the url prettier for humans. Why don't you use clean urls as most sites do: `domain.com/history` and `domain.com/team`? You can do this using rewriting rules so no one is interested in your internal script structure.

Comment: Hi arkascha, I appreciate your comment very much but you didn't really answer my question :-). Do search engines index domain.com/about.php#team or just the base page domain.com/about.php?

Comment: No I didn't answer your question. Please note that I wrote a comment, not an answer. And sorry, I am not sure about which search engines handle such anchors how. I am sceptical that they consider them.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Sorry I am new to StackOverflow. I am also skeptical :-)

Comment: You are welcome. And... the more I think about it, I'd say that there actually is not really a technical way to evaluate those named anchors. So I'd say quite definately no, such links are not treated as separate by search engines. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All search engines copies all the texts of your page. If you program server side on PHP, JSP, or HTML, the texts are all being taken by the search engine. If you are going to put an anchor link and it scrolls down to the section you want, it still works. It is being recorded as one page, in this case `about.php`.

But, if you start using javascript, and the text that you have is part of javascript, and not the server side scripts; then, search engines may not be able to read it because it only reads the text that are ready on load. For example:

```
document.write("This text will not be read by Search Engines");
```

So, if you are going to program your page, it is recommended to display the text first using server side scripting. If you ever want to hide the texts, you may use page effects after the server loads the texts, and it still will be read by the Search Engines.

Comment: Hi Franz, many thanks for your explanation. So just to clarify -- domain.com/about.php will be the only page that's indexed although domain.com/about.php#history and domain.com/about.php#team also exist?

Comment: Yes. The only page that will be indexed will be `domain.com/about.php`. It will not index any `domain.com/about.php#any_anchor_links`

Comment: Another thing is: `www.domain.com/about.php`, `www.domain.com/AbOUt.php`,  and `domain.com/about.php` will be considered different pages. So, make sure that your domain is properly set. Here is a link from the Google Web Masters: http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp/. You might want to know more.

Comment: anchors are not indexed as separate pages but Google sometimes keeps track of them. You may sometimes see "jump to" links inside some results which are anchor links that go to the part of the page that relates well to the search.